# Argument for Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I recently offered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708862/how-to-find-linearly-independent-vectors#comment7622451_3708862) slightly hand-wavy argument in response to the linked question regarding linear independence.  I wasn't confident enough to make it an answer, so I posted it as a tentative comment, and my question now is whether my argument works.  The goal is to find an $x$ that makes $$a_1 = (-1, 1, 0, x)\\
a_2 = (2, -3, 1, 2)\\
a_3 = (1, -2, 1, -1)$$

a linearly independent set, the possibility of which we'll interpret to be implied by the problem.  My thought process is basically:

1)  If we can make a geometric argument for finding such an $x$ with three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (at least an argument of the sort in the next step), then it should apply to $\mathbb{R}^4$ even though no such geometry is available,

2)  In $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e., remove the first element from each vector), the fact that a solution is possible means that $a_1$ is not trapped in the plane spanned by the other vectors, thus there can be at most a single value of $x$ where $a_1$ intersects the plane.  The slope of the plane must be rational, since it is determined by ratios of components of $a_2$ and $a_3$, but then picking any irrational $x$ would give $a_1$ an irrational slope, so that it couldn't possibly intersect with the plane.

Does this line of reasoning solve the problem?

Comment: I think there was needed to find _all the_ $x$ such that makes $a_1,a_2,a_3$ linearly independent in the original question, so the rationality don't go.

Comment: "*The goal is to find* **an** *x that makes...*"  No, the goal was to find *all such x* that makes it linearly independent.  Next "*even though no such geometry is available*"... what?  There is a geometry in $\Bbb R^4$.  What are you talking about?  There are planes and hyperplanes in $\Bbb R^4$ just like there are planes in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I also don't understand what objects you are talking about as "intersecting the plane" or not... if the plane was the span of the second two vectors, and we were to consider the span of the first vector... then they obviously intersect at least at the origin.  Perhaps you mean to talk about the first being *coplanar*... where does irrationality come into play there?  You have for instance $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(\sqrt{2},\pi,0)$ are all coplanar... despite the third containing irrational numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz My stated interpretation of the problem was that it excludes the coplanar possibility.  The line I referred to as potentially intersecting the plane is not the span of the first vector, but the set of points obtained via all possible values of $x$, which is in general affine, thus needn't intersect the plane at the origin.  I didn't mean to imply that there is no geometry in higher dimensions, but I don't think it's available for the type of visual reasoning we can apply in $\mathbb{R}^3$, at least I don't know how.